# Remote connection to postgres running on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling to enable remote connection on Postgres running on Ubuntu.  I've done the following steps:

1. Opened up the firewall; running sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN gives me:

   ```
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2947/postgres
   ```

   Added in listen_addresses to postgresql.conf:

   ```
   listen_addresses='*'            # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                   # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                   # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
   ```

   Added in the connection table in pg_hba.conf as follows:

   ```
   # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

   # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
   local   all             all                                     peer
   ```

I can connect locally but I cannot connect remotely; not even connecting via telnet works.  It just says connection refused.  Has anyone got an idea as to the cause of the problem?

Thanks.

Cheers,
Neil

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Restart postgres

Check if it's listening on all interfaces

```
# netstat -lnp --tcp | grep postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6096/postgres
```

Add `host` line to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Add a password for your user

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password username
```